# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'SQL: Column ' ' is not found.'

Tags: visual-foxpro

When I run my VFP query I'm getting:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'SQL: Column '     ' is not found.'

**Sample SQL**

```sql
SELECT a.Name
FROM [some-table] b
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix the table alias: `[some-table] a` should be `[some-table] b`

**Sample SQL**

```sql
SELECT b.Name
FROM [some-table] b
```

Comment: The answer is pretty obvious in this sample query but in a large query it is hard to tell what the problem is with that terrible error message